# Laplace Transform

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution, differential

Question: Use Laplace Transform to solve the following differential equation

$\ y''+y =sin(t); y(0)=1, y'(0)=-1 $

My try,where F(s) is the transform of f(t)=y(t)

$F(s)= \frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2} + \frac{s}{s^2+1} -\frac{1}{s^2+1} $

Then,using convolution for Laplace Transform in the first fraction and applying the transform in others

$y(t)= \int_0^t \sin(t-u)\sin(u)du + \cos t - \sin t $

My problem is here,because I'm reaching to a result that is different from the answer. My approach was

$$ \int_0^t \sin(t-u)\sin(u)du = \int_0^t (\sin(t)\cos(u)-\sin(u)\cos(t))\sin(u)du =$$

$$= \sin(t)\int_0^t\sin(u)\cos(u)du - \int_0^t\sin^2(u)\cos(t)du
=\frac{\sin^3(t)}{2}-\frac{\cos(t)}{2}\left(t-\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}\right) $$

And there is some problem in that resolution that I can't found. Someone can help please?

The answer is:

$ y(t)=\cos(t)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)-\frac{1}{2}t\cos(t) $

Comment: why don't you write all the steps ? let $g(t) = y''(t)+y(t)$ then $G(s) = ?$

Comment: by integration by parts : $\int_0^\infty y''(t) e^{-st} dt = y'(0) +s \int_0^\infty y'(t) e^{-st} dt = y'(0)+s y(0) + s^2 \int_0^\infty y(t) e^{-st} dt$ $ = y'(0)+s y(0) + s^2  Y(s) $ so $G(s) = y'(0)+s y(0) + (s^2+1) Y(s)$

Comment: What do you need convolutions for here?! What do you want to translate to and what for?

Comment: Don, my goal using convolution was to simplify the computation of the inverse transform of $ 1/(s^2+1)^2 $ once I know it is $ \mathcal{L-1}(sint) $ I can use it to compute $ \mathcal{L-1}(sint) * \mathcal{L-1}(sint) $

Comment: @JJWho But why? Look at any decent table of Laplace transform (and inverses). You have there $$\mathcal L^{-1}\left(\frac{2a^3}{(s^2+a^2)^2}\right)=\sin at-at\cos at$$ It is direct!

Comment: Yes Don, but that was a question of a old exam of my teacher and that inverse wasn't in the table. Here in Brazil we have only the simplest table in the exam. I don't how is at your country.

Comment: @JJWho It's not a matter of country but of what the web has. Now, if your teacher *gives you* the table of transforms and that's all you can use then perhaps yes: you would have to do some hokus pokus. Still, I can't see why would you relate that involution with what you want.

Comment: @DonAntonio ok my mistake $G(s) = -y'(0)-s y(0) + (s^2+1)Y(s)$ (integration by parts is too difficult for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have no idea what you did there and why did you go for convolutions as the initial conditions are for zero and it is straightforward then, but the following is what I did:

Putting $\;\mathcal L\{y(t)\}(s)=Y(s)\;$  and applying the transform to the equation with the conditions, we get:

$$s^2Y(s)-s+1+Y(s)=\frac1{s^2+1}\implies (s^2+1)Y(S)=\frac1{s^2+1}+s-1\implies$$

$$Y(s)=\frac1{(s^2+1)^2}+\frac s{s^2+1}-\frac1{s^2+1}=\frac12\frac{2\cdot1^3}{(s^2+1)^2}+\frac s{s^2+1}-\frac1{s^2+1}\implies$$

$$y(t)=\frac12\left(\sin t-t\cos t\right)+\cos t-\sin t=\cos t-\frac12\sin t-\frac12t\cos t$$

Comment: Don, I understand your idea and agree it is simpler than my . But I would like to know where is my mistake.

Comment: @JJWho I just can't see how to relate that convolution to what you wrote...

Comment: @JJWho I told you : your main mistake is that you didn't write all the steps

Comment: @user1952009 all the steps I skip is consequente of the table. Note that the same conclusion about F(s) or Y(s) that I reach Don reach too. My main doubt was about the convolution step. But I see it is something 'well-know' by tables etc.

Comment: @JJWho you main mistake is to use tables instead of re-proving everything (especially when you are not sure)   (and here re-proving means adding a 3 lines proof)